# Issues installing mxnet GPU R package for Amazon deep learning AMI

Tags: r, linux, amazon-ec2, mxnet

I am having trouble installing mxnet GPU for R on Amazon deep learning linux AMI. The environment variables are such a mess that it’s a nightmare for any non-expert sys-admin to figure out.

Step 1: install the ridiculous amount of missing/broken programs and R packages

```
sudo yum install R
sudo yum install libxml2-devel   
sudo yum install cairo-devel
sudo yum install giflib-devel
sudo yum install libXt-devel
sudo R
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("igraph/rigraph")
install.packages(‘DiagrammeR’) 
install.packages(‘roxygen2’)
install.packages(‘rgexf’)
install.packages(‘influenceR’)
install.packages(‘Cairo’)
install.packages(“imager”)
```

Step 2: edit the config.mk file

```
cd /src/mxnet
cp make/config.mk .
echo "USE_BLAS=openblas" >>config.mk
echo "ADD_CFLAGS += -I/usr/include/openblas" >>config.mk
echo "ADD_LDFLAGS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs" >>config.mk
echo "USE_CUDA=1" >>config.mk
echo "USE_CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda" >>config.mk
echo "USE_CUDNN=1" >>config.mk
```

*note even though the USE_CUDA_PATH is set, it STILL cannot find libcudart.so and needs to be linked in the make command (shown later)

Step 3: make new config file so make command can find libcudart.so

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf
```

add /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64

```
sudo ldconfig
```

- note this was posted by nvidia but does absolutely nothing to help the make rpkg

Step 4: set up R directories

```
Rscript -e "install.packages('devtools', repo = 'https://cran.rstudio.com')"
cd R-package
Rscript -e "library(devtools); library(methods); options(repos=c(CRAN='https://cran.rstudio.com'));
```

install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)"
    cd ..

step 5: make

```
cd /src/mxnet
sudo make -j8
```

Result:

make CXX=g++ DEPS_PATH=/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/deps -C /home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/ps-lite ps
cd /home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/dmlc-core; make libdmlc.a USE_SSE=1 config=/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/config.mk; cd /home/ec2-user/src/mxnet
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/dmlc-core'
make[1]:`libdmlc.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/dmlc-core'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/ps-lite'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `ps'.
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/ps-lite'
ar crv lib/libmxnet.a

*note, even when changing the config.mk file, the make command always returns ‘nothing to update’

Step 6: attempt to make rpkg

```
Cd /src/mxnet
Sudo make rpkg
```

Error: 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mxnet’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'mxnet', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs/libmxnet.so':
  libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed

So it’s looking in a location that doesn’t exist: /usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs/
When the file actually lives: 
/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/R-package/inst/libs/libmxnet.so
or
/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/lib/libmxnet.so

What I’ve tried so far:

```
sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 make rpkg
```

This will fix the missing libcudart.so.8.0 issue but it is simply replace with:
libmklml_intel.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory as well as the original ‘cannot find libmxnet.so

Also tried:
1. actually creating directories (/usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs/) and then copying libmxnet.so there
Result: same error

2. adding /home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/R-package/inst/libs/ to the make command
   sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/src/mxnet/R-package/inst/libs make rpkg
   Result: same error
3. a ridiculous amount of environment labels all of which failed:

   export MXNET_HOME=/usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs/
   export MXNET_HOME=/usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs/libmxnet.so
   sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs /usr/lib
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs/libmxnet.so /usr/lib
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmklml_intel.so /usr/lib
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libiomp5.so /usr/lib
   sudo ln -s /usr/local /usr/lib
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/R/library/mxnet/libs/libmxnet.so /usr/lib
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0

In all ONE of these worked, because I briefly got mxnet R package working before it fell apart again. I’ve dropped 50+ hours into this installation, which, frankly is ridiculous. Tougher to install the software then it is to program an actual net....

I don’t have 5+ years of linux sys admin knowledge so if you’d like please be a bit more helpful then ‘fix environment variables.’ I can tell that’s obviously what’s wrong yet have no idea what ‘fix environment variables’ entails.

To top it off, even after successful install of the R package, it STILL won’t work until setting Rstudio server’s config file to: rsession-ld-library-path=/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the following when running any sudo commands.

```
sudo -E make -j8
```

This means that it will preserve the env variables when running as superuser. You shouldn't have to add a new config file for the make to find the libraries. Just preserving the env variables using the above command should be enough.

Comment: I tried:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/ec2-user/src/mxnet/R-

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/user/src/mxnet/R-package/inst/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/ec2-user/src/mxnet/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0

I used sudo ldconfig after export commands, then added -E to the make statement per a stackoverflow suggestion 
sudo -E make rpkg
same cant find libmxnet.so and libcudart.so.9.0 error

It only fails on the 'testing if package can be loaded' part. Is there an option to run make rpkg and R CMD INSTALL in non-check modes?

Comment: Your environment variables are wrong. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user instead LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/ec2-user and for cuda LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Are these typos ? Also if you dont want everything in rpkg to be run, you can comment out the lines in Makefile under rpkg and rpkgtest.

Comment: I tried export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda:LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the -E command and still no luck.

The other option is to build rpackage without testing, then somehow configure R/Rstudio to load the correct environment variable.

Where is that make file located?

Comment: Makefile is located in the mxnet root folder

Comment: You nailed it. It was two environment variables: 
/usr/local/lib/ and =/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64. Adding them to the environment and config.mk files helped immensely.

Comment: It no longer works. I have been trying to update to a newer mxnet version because the version I got working is bugged. Cloned from repo, updated LD vars and config.mk, attempted build...failed, unable to find cuda.h. To make matters worse the aws AMIs have changed, the 'conda' version I can't access the mxnet folder and the 'base' version doesnt have it installed.